# Корректно ли предложение?

Tags: стилистика

Корректно ли написано: «История развития ОВД свидетельствует о том, что вопросы наделения данного ведомства уголовно-процессуальными полномочиями неоднозначно решались на разных этапах развития министерства внутренних дел»?

Answer (score 1):

Нормально. Не хуже того, что частенько приходится слышать от чиновников.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вполне. Только очень уж "грузовое". Нельзя ли как-то упростить?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы убрал повтор слова "развития" и во втором случае заменил его (работы, существования, реформирования, деятельности...). Кроме того, слово "Министерство" должно быть написано с прописной буквы. Но это уже не стилистика.